# Unmatched users filter does not show application-only users in OneLogin

Tags: scim, onelogin

I have a SCIM application with some users who are not in OneLogin. When I go to Users tab and select "Unmatched Users" (to import them) I should see the users who are only in my application but I can't see any.

OneLogin makes a request to our endpoint (`/svc/scim/v1/Users?startIndex=1&count=100`) and we return the users.

This is a sample response that we return:

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
  ],
  "totalResults": 1,
  "itemsPerPage": 1,
  "startIndex": 1,
  "Resources": [
    {
      "userName": "xy@email.com",
      "emails": [
        {
          "primary": true,
          "value": "xy@email.com"
        }
      ],
      "active": true,
      "id": "94724df5-2338-45a3-8b96-0f68afd273d4",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Now, I send givenName / familyName back still can't see users in OneLogin

```
 {
      "userName": "xy+username@gmail.com",
      "name": {
        "givenName": "hasname",
        "familyName": "hasname"
      },
      "emails": [
        {
          "primary": true,
          "value": "xy+username@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "active": true,
      "id": "d5f6632b-970b-4476-9465-b275907fccf4",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably rejecting these records because they don't contain a firstname & lastname.

We're working on an enhancement for this, but you're going to end up with a pretty bad user experience because these values are what's used to help guide the user to who's who.

So without these values, everyone is going to display as unknown unknown (although I believe the username will still be displayed)

BTW: You're the first SCIM implementer we've run across that isn't supporting these values. You might consider it if your application is going to be used outside of an "in-house" application.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back however I still cannot see the users even if I fill the name in our application

Comment: Try also including
        "formatted": "Noname McNoname" as part of the name object.

This is similarly required (at least for now) as part of the core schema.

Comment: {
      "userName": "edewdwe@fdsf.hu",
      "name": {
        "givenName": "dewed",
        "familyName": "dewwd",
        "formatted": "dewed dewwd"
      },
      "emails": [
        {
          "primary": true,
          "value": "edewdwe@fdsf.hu"
        }
      ],
      "active": true,
      "id": "19f16e43-54bc-46f8-a5bc-326fd9786b8b",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"
      ]
    }

Comment: Let me check our logs and see if I can't figure out what's what.

Comment: It's not showing any errors on our end. Mind sending an email to devsupport@onelogin.com with some details of what you're doing and seeing in our UI?

With this I can file an engineering ticket to investigate